# File size shown by "du -k" is different in different file systems (PRAMFS and FLASH)

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

I have a file `xyz.log` which is of size 1.72MB.

In FLASH file system: If I run `du -k xyz.log` output is `1761 xyz.log`.

I copied the same file to RAM storage and run the `du -k xyz.log` output is `221 xyz.log`.

If I run `ls -lrth`, the file size in both file systems is same:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     aspa       1.7M Jan  1 00:25 xyz.log
```

RAM file system is `pramfs` and FLASH file system is `jffs2`.

Why the disk usage of same file is different in different file systems and how to get the same disk usage in all file systems?

Answer (score 5):

use `du --apparent-size -k`

from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html):

> `‘--apparent-size’`
>
> Print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage. The apparent size of a file is the number of bytes reported by `wc -c` on regular files, or more generally, `ls -l --block-size=1` or `stat --format=%s`. For example, a file containing the word `‘zoo’` with no newline would, of course, have an apparent size of 3. Such a small file may require anywhere from 0 to 16 KiB or more of disk space, depending on the type and configuration of the file system on which the file resides. However, a sparse file created with this command:
>
> ```
>           dd bs=1 seek=2GiB if=/dev/null of=big
> ```
>
> has an apparent size of 2 GiB, yet on most modern systems, it actually uses almost no disk space.

Comment: `du --help` is not showing `--apparent-size` option in my machine. linux version is `Linux 135.250.15.70 2.6.27.39`.